# mask image as a circle in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to 'mask' an image, turning it into a circle. The code below loads, resizes and shows the image but no circle.

In my html div which refers to my controller:

```
ng-style='obj.avatar_style'
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.obj.avatarURL = UserModel.getAvatarURL();

$scope.obj.avatar_style = {'width': '30px', 'height': '30px', 'border-radius': '15px', 'background-image': 'url(' + $scope.obj.avatarURL + ')', 'background-size': '30px 30px'}
```

Comment: could you give us some feedback about whether the answers you got were helpful

Comment: Answers from both  Simon H  and Goldenowner work. I overlooked I had a no border-radius for all elements somewhere in my css...

Comment: Great news. Then you need to mark the question answered

Comment: I don't see how to mark a question answered?

Comment: You well see a little tick mark next to each answer. Click on in one if those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is something you wanted to get, you can add the other styles yourself.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.avatar_style = {
    'border-radius': '50px'
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif" ng-style="avatar_style">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

ngStyle is for setting individual style elements. In your case you should move most of your styles to e.g. thre `.avatar` class in your stylesheet and then in your html something like this

```
<div class="avatar" ng-style="{'background-image': $scope.obj.avatarURL}">
```